# Calculating number needed to reach a certain percentage

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a function that will tell me how many more is needed to reach a certain percentage.

This is the function I've gotten so far:

```
private static int CalculateHowManyNeeded(int TotalPallets, int PalletsDelivered, int MinReqPercentage = 25)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32((MinReqPercentage / 100.00 * TotalPallets) - PalletsDelivered);
}
```

However, my method fails to give me the right answer if I have `TotalPallets = 2`, and `palletsDelivered = 0`.  I'm expecting to get `1`.. but my method returns `0`...

What is the best way I can fix this problem?

Comment: Was not able to reproduce, [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qriwGD) for me.

Comment: sorry about that .. instead of 3.. its 2.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 of 0.5 will return 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is all you need -

```
    private static int CalculateHowManyNeeded(int TotalPallets, int PalletsDelivered, int MinReqPercentage = 25)
    {
        return (int) Math.Ceiling(MinReqPercentage * 0.01 * TotalPallets) - PalletsDelivered;
    }
```

Do the following output look good to you -

```
Console.WriteLine(CalculateHowManyNeeded(2, 0));     // 1
Console.WriteLine(CalculateHowManyNeeded(2, 1, 49)); // 0
Console.WriteLine(CalculateHowManyNeeded(2, 1, 50)); // 0
Console.WriteLine(CalculateHowManyNeeded(2, 1, 51)); // 1
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Double_) as written in the docs will return next:

> `value`, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If `value` is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

So in case of `0.5` you will get `0`. Next depended on desired output, if you want to round also this halfway points to the "upper bound" you can use [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_MidpointRounding_) with [`MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-5.0) (round to nearest mode: when a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest number that is away from zero.):

```
private static int CalculateHowManyNeeded(int TotalPallets, int PalletsDelivered, int MinReqPercentage = 25)
{
    return (int)Math.Round((MinReqPercentage / 100.00 * TotalPallets) - PalletsDelivered, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

If you want to get the smallest integral value greater than or equal to the specified number (i.e. 1 for 0.1, 0.2 etc.) the you can use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=net-5.0) as [@Harsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13557443/harsh) suggested in his answer.

Comment: does it need .Dump() ? works fine without this.

Comment: @PeterHenry thank you, removed. Artifact from LINQPad =)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try something like this:

```
private static int CalculateHowManyNeeded(int TotalPallets, int PalletsDelivered, int MinReqPercentage = 25)
{
    int result =  Convert.ToInt32((MinReqPercentage / 100.00 * TotalPallets) - PalletsDelivered);
    result = result <= 0 ? 1 : result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What if `result = 2.5`?